# sql query that went it runs it repeats the same result by the number of users

Tags: mysql

Hi hope someone can advise

I have a sql query that went it runs it repeats the same result by the number of users (entries) made

for example:

```
post_id
20
20
19
19
18
18
```

Here is the query it takes no arguments, could someone explain why this is happening please?

Thanks

```
SELECT DISTINCT post_look.post_id, post_look.look_id, post_look.date_posted,     looks.title, looks.item_id, user.user_id, user.first_name, user.last_name,    user_account.profile_image, user_account.account_status, add_profile_images.image_name
FROM post_look
JOIN looks ON looks.look_id = post_look.look_id
JOIN add_look_item ON add_look_item.look_id = looks.look_id
JOIN item ON item.item_id = add_look_item.item_id
JOIN add_images ON add_images.item_id = item.item_id
JOIN user_item ON user_item.item_id = item.item_id
JOIN user_account ON user_account.account_id = user_item.account_id
JOIN user ON user.user_id = user_account.user_id
JOIN users_profile_images ON users_profile_images.account_id = user_account.account_id
JOIN add_profile_images ON add_profile_images.image_id = users_profile_images.image_id
ORDER BY post_look.post_id DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: what result are you expecting?

Comment: Hi Priyank - one result per user per select so would return 20,19,18 for example

Comment: You are returning several columns in your result. Are you sure that you have **two completely identical rows**? What does your statement return if you only selet `post_look.post_id` and remove all other columns?

Comment: Hi lieven, if I remove all others from the select just leaving post_id it works fine. Obviously I loose attributes that I require!

Comment: @Alan - than you need to make a choice. You can either have distinct post_id's using the method Jaroslaw described (and *loose* attributes) or retain all information and deal with duplicate post_id's.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT c1, c2, c3
```

means that `{c1, c2, c3}` will be distinct.

You should consider adding `GROUP BY post_look.post_id` to your query.

See the difference here:

- [DISTINCT](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e6890/1)
- [GROUP BY](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e6890/3)

Comment: GROUP BY I am new to this so this is interesting, thanks Jaroslaw do have an example?

Comment: @Alan - Simply add the entire posted statement just before your order by clause.

Comment: You can read more about group by here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html

Comment: Thanks Jaroslaw for the explanation and link much appreciated ! :)

Comment: @you are right it is a shame you cannot select two as one does demonstrate the solution however Jaroslaw gives the explanation! And will be useful in the future @ Jaroslaw, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Would you please try it?

```
SELECT post_look.post_id, post_look.look_id, post_look.date_posted,     looks.title, looks.item_id, user.user_id, user.first_name, user.last_name,    user_account.profile_image, user_account.account_status, add_profile_images.image_name
FROM post_look
JOIN looks ON looks.look_id = post_look.look_id
JOIN add_look_item ON add_look_item.look_id = looks.look_id
JOIN item ON item.item_id = add_look_item.item_id
JOIN add_images ON add_images.item_id = item.item_id
JOIN user_item ON user_item.item_id = item.item_id
JOIN user_account ON user_account.account_id = user_item.account_id
JOIN user ON user.user_id = user_account.user_id
JOIN users_profile_images ON users_profile_images.account_id = user_account.account_id
JOIN add_profile_images ON add_profile_images.image_id = users_profile_images.image_id
GROUP BY post_look.post_id
ORDER BY post_look.post_id DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: This is identical to what Jaroslaw proposed?!

Comment: @Lieven yes this is thanks for example sarwar026 this works a treat thanks Lieven for fault finding!